# Hosting webservices for android App

Tags: java, android, ios, web-services

I am really new to web apps and web services... But i have created a webservice and it's working in localhost(apache glassfish) but i need to deploy this thing in an external se(in java)rver so that every one can consume that web service via my app..Unfortunately am unaware of this technique. 
so can anybody help in this problem ? Can i host this webprogram in normal godaddy webserver or is there any other way for this..in fact, my app is a small one and i need the solution for small apps or startups

thank you

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish hosting will be hard to find. If your application is not GlassFish specific and can be run on JBoss, then you might try RedHat [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/). They have free plan for small application load and you get for free server administration, database administration, deployment is easy, you might concentrate on coding only.

Another option is to use [Heroku](http://java.heroku.com/). You will also need to neglect GlassFish, but they have easy path to creation of REST web service backend.

Comment: what about google app engine..i just heared about that

Comment: Google app engine is ok too, as far as its functinality is sufficient for your needs (there are some restrictions, not all JEE spec is available, similarly to Heroku, BTW)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend renting a server at amazon:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

You can take already existing images with GlassFish and a Database or take a naked CentOs/ Red Hat Image and install your GlassFish manually. The link provides a table with all prices. A m3.medium costs $0.070 per Hour. It's super fast and flexible and you have high availability.

In NetBeans you can deploy on a remote server via: Services -> Servers -> Add Server:
Just enter your ip, username and password for the GlassFish Server:
[image]

**Or**

You can host your Project on a Raspberry Pi. Maybe the power is enough for a small Web App:
http://www.thehecklers.org/2013/10/27/glassfish4-raspberrypi/
Advantage: It's cheap and you can learn and control a lot.

Comment: That's also good option, the points is someone has to be administrator of that CentOS machine - probably there will be not a lot of admin tasks to do, but still... and if something breaks in Linux, you need to fix that by yourself.